What does chikis mean
Saw it in a video of someone saying they're gonna miss their chikis and I wanna know what it means so I have more context to the sentence.

Hard to say without more context from the video. Can you transcribe what comes before/after the expression?

According to what was discussed here chiqui can be also used as nickname for a girl that you like. As Gustavson mentioned is short for "chiquita".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"chikis" might be a spelling used in text messages for "chiquis" meaning "their kids" (their small ones / their little ones).
"Chiquis" is short for "chiquitos".

Just for completing the answer, about the way @user36381 wrote "chiki", there is a word in basque languaje which is "txiki" that means exactly "small". https://hiztegiak.elhuyar.eus/eu_es/txiki
